# Proving the set of true expressions in a theory cannot be expressed in this theory

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

Suppose we have a first-order theory $T_C$ that includes a binary function $C$.
$C$ is a bijection $\Sigma \to \mathbb{N}$ where $\Sigma$ is the alphabet of $T_C$.
The function $C$ is defined as follows:

$$C(i,j) = \text{to_num}(\text{to_num}^{-1}(i) . \text{to_num}^{-1}(j))$$

$i,j$ are natural numbers, "." is a string concatenation.

We are supposed to prove that the set of sentences $\varphi$ $\{T_C \models \varphi\}$ is not expressible in the theory $T_C$. The proof must use Tarski's undefinability theorem.

I have managed to discover that $C(i,j)$ allows for addition of natural numbers if encoded this way:

$$\text{to_num}() = 0$$
$$\text{to_num}(1) = 1$$
$$\text{to_num}(11) = 2$$
$$\text{to_num}(\text{n times 1}) = n$$

$$\text{to_num}^{-1}(0) = \text{empty string}$$
$$\text{to_num}^{-1}(1) = \text{1}$$
$$\text{to_num}^{-1}(2) = \text{11}$$
$$\text{to_num}^{-1}(n) = \text{n times 1}$$

Therefore,

$$a+b = C(a,b) = \text{to_num}(\text{to_num}^{-1}(a) . \text{to_num}^{-1}(b))$$

This works, because we concatenate $a$ ones with $b$ ones, which when turned to numbers gives the result of the addition.

I know how to construct a proof of undefinability, given the theory of Peano arithmetics and its Godel's encoding (I know how to construct the contradiction). However, I first need to map my theory $T_C$ to Peano's arithmetic theory, but I am still unsure about how to do it.